# Syntax error while trying to insert date with interval value to a date time field

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code that is meant to insert values into the database and it looks like I am having problem around the `DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY))`;

There is a field in the backend tabled called `vkeyexpire` which is a datetime column and I am passing a "s" as the parameter in the `bind_param` statement

I have tried and can't seem to get it working.

This is my code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO register (firstname, lastname, email,password, classof,country, town, comment,verified, vkey,vkeyexpire) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('ssssssssiss', $firstname, $lastname,$email,$password,$classof,$country,$town,$comment, $verified, $vkey, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY));
$stmt->execute();
```

I am getting the below error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '2' (T_LNUMBER), expecting ')'
> in C:\xampp\htdocs\USS\controllers\register_server.php on line 110

Comment: `DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)` is not valid PHP code. Why not add it to the query directly if it does not need any escaping?

Answer (score 1):

You can't put SQL functions in PHP code. You need to call `DATE_ADD()` in the SQL.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO register (firstname, lastname, email,password, classof,country, town, comment,verified, vkey,vkeyexpire) 
        VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?,?,?,?,?,DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY))";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('ssssssssis', $firstname, $lastname,$email,$password,$classof,$country,$town,$comment, $verified, $vkey);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: DO I have to define the DATE_ADD() as a default value in MYsql backend table?

Comment: Why would you need to do that if you're assigning it explicitly in the `INSERT` query? Before MySQL 8.0.13 you're not even allowed to use an expression as a default value.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the INSERT prepared statement in  php Using DATE ADD using NOW(), + INTERVAL 2 DAY) in the value section of the insert statement.

In the bind_Param, do not include it in the string.

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO register (firstname, lastname, email,password, classof,country, town, comment,verified, vkey,vkeyexpire) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?,?,?,?,?,now() + INTERVAL 2 day)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssssssis', $firstname, $lastname,$email,$password,$classof,$country,$town,$comment, $verified, $vkey);
        if ($stmt->execute())
        {
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTF2l.png)